# Create Dynamic Array from one column based on autofilter criteria

Tags: excel, vba

**I am trying to create a dashboard where:**

- It takes column A and creates an array of filtered names (autofilter) based off columns C, D, or E
- C, D, and E only have Yes or No
- I will only use one of the columns (C,D,E) to filter the names.
- I then use the stored array to manipulate data.

**The problem I am running into though is that when I use the autofilter feature and then use my code, I am unable to capture just the filtered data along with the last row.**
So far I have been manually filtering the data and then testing my code.

```
Sub tester()

  Dim LastRow As Integer

  LastRow = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("employees").UsedRange.Rows.count
  vasWksNames = UniquesFromRange(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("employees").Range("A2:A" & LastRow))

  If UBound(arr) = -1 Then
      Debug.Print "no values found"
  Else
      Debug.Print "got array of unique values"
  End If

End Sub

Function UniquesFromRange(rng As Range)

  Dim d As Object, c As Range, tmp
  Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
  For Each c In rng.Cells
     tmp = Trim(c.Value)
     If Len(tmp) > 0 Then
        If Not d.Exists(tmp) Then d.Add tmp, 1
     End If
  Next c
  UniquesFromRange = d.keys

End Function
```

Unfiltered data -> Filtered data -> Create Array

Anything helps!

[image: Unfiltered data]

[image: Filtered data]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` gets all visible cells.

Please try.

```vb
Function UniquesFromRange(rng As Range)
  Dim d As Object, c As Range, tmp
  Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
  For Each c In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells
     tmp = Trim(c.Value)
     If Len(tmp) > 0 Then
        If Not d.Exists(tmp) Then d.Add tmp, 1
     End If
  Next c
  UniquesFromRange = d.keys
End Function
```

Microsoft reference document:

> [Range.SpecialCells method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

> [XlCellType enumeration (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlcelltype?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)